# Why/how does winapi reverse the order of messages?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

Consider the following code:

```
CCritialSection listLock;
std::list<CString> messageList;
extern MyApp theApp;    // public inheritance from CWinApp
const int aMessageNumber = WM_APP + 123;

void MyApp::EnqueueMessageForUIThread( const CString message )
{
    CSingleLock lock( &listLock, TRUE );
    messageList.push_back( message );
    theApp.m_pMainWnd->PostMessage( aMessageNumber  );
}

void MyApp:PopupMessageFromNonUIThread( void)
{
    // This function is called via ON_MESSAGE( aMessageNumber, ... )
    CSingleLock lock( &listLock, TRUE );
    bool messagesAvailable( !messageList.empty() );
    while ( messagesAvailable )
    {
        const CString message( messageList.front() );
        messageList.pop_front();
//      lock.Unlock();
        AfxMessageBox( message, MB_ICONINFORMATION );
//      lock.Lock();
        messagesAvailable = !messageList.empty();
    }
}
```

As the two function names suggest, these functions are intended to pop up messages in the UI thread that originate from non-UI threads - bad things happen on Windows when UI functions are called from non-UI threads.

It would surely be better if the two `lock.Unlock()` and `lock.Lock()` lines were not commented out. This would allow more messages to be enqueued while each pop-up message awaits user response - the non-UI thread(s) would not have to block and wait for `listLock` to be available.

However... at least in the context in which I employ these functions, I consistently enqueue three messages in order, and yet pop them up to the user in the reverse order. How is this possible?

In case it matters (and I don't believe it does), these functions are part of the code of a "main app" which runs in conjunction with a "helper app" on a Windows PC. There is another (identical) PC running the same two apps. Communications between all parties is via Windows sockets - the main apps only talk to the helpers; the helpers talk to other helpers across a network.

The three messages I consistently see in order with the above code, but in reverse order when I uncomment the two Lock/Unlock lines, are part of a "loopback" test - I send a message from one main app to the other, get the first (local) helper to acknowledge it, then the second (remote) helper to acknowledge it, then the second (remote) main app to acknowledge it.

Capturing packets on the network confirms that packets are sent/received in the expected order. Numbering the messages as they arrive confirms they are received in order. There is only one receiving thread, and no possibility of re-entering the `EnqueueMessageForUIThread()` function multiple times before it completes.

Nonetheless, somewhere between calling the `EnqueueMessageForUIThread()` function with a (numbered) message, and having the `PopupMessageForNonUIThread()` function pop it up, those messages will be popped up in reverse if I remove the comments from the `lock.Unlock()` and `lock.Lock()`.

How?

Comment: MessageBox() is pretty dangerous, it causes re-entrancy because it pumps a message loop itself.  Which is liable to get your function called again.  Which indeed makes it look like messages are processed in reverse order.  Do *not* use message boxes to debug your code.  Use the debugger or tracing.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28VS.85%29.aspx for ways to write to the Debug Output tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostMessage is thread safe, it is *designed* to forward messages to other threads. That means that the thread-unsafety you are experiencing lies in your code.

In this case, you are opening a message box. The message box itself runs the message loop and so, if you set a break point in PopupMessageFromNonUIThread, you will find that you are pulling the second and third messages from the queue before the first message box has done anything.

You will need to implement your own modality for this, which doesn't require locking for the message pump, just for the transfer queue.

```
bool MyApp::getNextMessage(CString& into)
{
    CSingleLock lock( &listLock, TRUE );
    if ( messageList.empty() )
        return false;
    into = messageList.front();
    messageList.pop_front();
    return true;
}

void MyApp:PopupMessageFromNonUIThread( void)
{
    static bool displaying = false;
    if (displaying)
        return;

    displaying = true;

    // This function is called via ON_MESSAGE( aMessageNumber, ... )
    CString message;
    while ( getNextMessage(message) )
    {
        AfxMessageBox( message, MB_ICONINFORMATION );
    }

    displaying = false;
}
```

Oh, I know it's not the most efficient mutex strategy ... but you are displaying a message box - optimizing the locking strategy you use around it is not important.

Comment: ... or as you and @Hans Passant point out, use something other than a message box!